# 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.12 Logotype extension - how can it be generated from openssl command line

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, openssl, x.509

If you look at this subCA Certificate from Verisign http://www.tbs-certificats.com/FAQ/en/495.html?p=en/495.html

It has the following field

```
1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.12:
    0_.].[0Y0W0U..image/gif0!0.0...+..............k...j.H.,{..0%.#http://logo.verisign.com/vslogo.gif
```

How can I create a cert using openssl commandline which has this extension?

Comment: What is the function and purpose of Logotype?

Comment: A [quick search](http://oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.12) reveals it's documented in [RFC 3709](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3709.html). From there you should be able to describe an [arbitrary extension](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/x509v3_config.html#ARBITRARY-EXTENSIONS) to OpenSSL using [ASN.1 generation strings](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/ASN1_generate_nconf.html). Let me know if you're still interested and I'll write this up in detail as an answer.

Comment: @Calrion - yes I am still interested. And than you very much.